# reorder django dynamic form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I am not able to reorder django form field which I am generating dynamically.

```
class VideoForm(forms.Form):
  video_width_height = forms.CharField()

  video_fps = forms.IntegerField()

  video_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VIDEO_TYPES) #VIDEO_TYPES has been defined above

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(VideoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    with connection.cursor() as c:
        c.execute('SELECT companyName from productionCompany')
        self.fields['production'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(i[0], i[0]) for i in c.fetchall()])
```

Now, I have tried `field_order = ['production','video_width_height', 'video_fps', 'video_type']`

But still it shows `production` field at the bottom of the form.

The thing is that it successfully changes the order of static fields like video_fps, video_type and video_width_height.

```
field_order = ['production','video_type', 'video_width_height', 'video_fps']
```

But the dynamic field is always at the bottom.

Any help on this?

Comment: Did you try `forms.ModelChoiceField` for your `video_type` field? Is it going to be a model instance?

Comment: its not a model instance actually, and I dont want to create one. Is there any other way buddy?

Comment: Hmm, no idea. Never had this before. But, if you have just a few fields, just type your own html code for the form if none of hacks works.

Answer (score 0):

```
# insde your __init__ logic
...
dynamically_generated_fieldnames_order = [
    'production',
    'video_type',
    'video_width_height',
    'video_fps'
]
self.fields.keyOrder = dynamically_generated_fieldnames_order
...
```

When i needed something close to this i used that `keyOrder` to fix it, i hope it work for your too.